# Npgsql ADO.Net can't set PostgreSQL connection properties

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I followed the guide here: 
https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider#install-npgsqlddexprovidervsix

When I want to add new ADO.NET EDM I have to stop at step nr. 9

Simply I can't edit any connection properties every time when I try to change a property VS alert appeared...
[Screenshot here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0uFIL5hC_70WTN5WDJvS2ZyekE/edit?usp=sharing)

Do you have any idea?

Machine: Win 7 prof x64 SP; VS2012 prof u4

Answer (score 0):

You may not have Npgsql in GAC. Checkout this section where possible errors are explained: 
https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider#how-to-check-if-npgsql-ddex-was-correctly-loaded

I hope it helps.